# Create a UICollectionView that scrolls with another UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have already built out 2 collection views, 1 horizontally scrolling (at the top) & 1 vertically scrolling (at the middle - bottom) that are used to view 2 different sets of content in my Objective-C iOS application similar to this Instagram screenshot:

[image]

I am trying to add functionality to make it so that the horizontally scrolling Collection View disappears when the user scrolls up on the vertically scrolling one.  What is the best way to accomplish this task?  I have looked up tutorials on adding a collection view in another collection view's cell but I cant find anything on just adding a collection view to the 1st cell of another collection view.  What would be the best way to accomplish this functionality?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should you use UITableView with UICollectionView. On the screeshot, I think horizontal collectionview is embedded in first cell of the tableview. And when use starts to scroll tableview, first row is gone as you want.

**Edit**

Create uitableview with 2 prototype cells. Create horizontall collectionview and embed it in first cell of tableview, this is first prototype cell. Then create second prototype cell for images. And when user will start scroll the tableview first cell will gone, as you want.

Comment: It would also be fine to embed the horizontal collection view in the first cell of a vertical collection view.

Comment: Would the tableView only have 2 cells? 1 for the horizontal collection view and one for the vertical?

Comment: @Roger99 If you mean prototype cell, then yes. But I tnink you can use one collection view(in first cell for horizontal collectionview) and other table for vertical. But you should use it as you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to go with the other suggested method of embedding the horizontal collection view into the top cell of the vertical collection view, you could use the vertical collection view's scrolling callbacks (`scrollViewDidScroll`, since `UICollectionView` subclasses `UIScrollView`). When the vertical collection view scrolls, you can apply a transform to the top collection view to move it off the top of the screen based on the `contentOffset` of the vertical collection view, and then have it reappear once the `contentOffset` approaches 0.

Keep in mind that with this approach, the vertical collection view's frame will likely be the height of the screen minus the height of the horizontal collection view. Therefore, you will need a bit of extra logic to expand the vertical collection view's frame to take up the whole screen once the horizontal collection view has disappeared from sight. Otherwise, you will have an awkward blank bar at the top of the screen where the horizontal collection view initially was while you scroll.

Answer (score 0):

You have two scroll view lets call it "cvHorizontal" and "cvVertical".

You can manage scrollViewDidScroll method to hide cvHorizontal when scrolled up and show cvHorizontal when scrolled down.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    if (lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y){
       [self showCategory:YES];
        lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    } else if (lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
         [self showCategory:NO];
         lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    }
}


-(void)showCategory:(BOOL)flag{
    if(flag){
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6 animations:^{
            if(cvHorizontal.hidden ){
                cvHorizontal.hidden=NO;
                cvHorizontalHeight.constant=65.0f;//manage the cvHorizontal height and all the other constraints calculation if any
            }
        }];
    }else {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6 animations:^{
            cvHorizontal.hidden=YES;
            cvHorizontalHeight.constant=0;
        }];
    }
}
```